# Getting a request parameter with a period using ${param}

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, el

I have a request parameter (I cannot change it) with . in it (e.g. `app.username=foo`) how can I get it with `$param{app.username}` also I have some number in request parameter (e.g `app.125=abc`) how can it get it with JSP EL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[]` operator

```
  ${requestScope['app.125']}
```

This `[]` operator was introduced to overcome this issue. We can use non-standard java identifiers using `[]`.

The `dot` operator provides limited functionality because the identifier has to be a valid java identifier. e.g. `${request.somParameterName}` it cannot include the parameters as you have mentioned. Only `[]` comes to the resque.